# Counterexample about representation of parametrized curves.

Tags: differential-geometry

In my book it says that in $\mathbb{R}^3$ there are parametrized curves which cannot be seen as the intersection of surfaces given by the expressions $F(x,y,z)=0,G(x,y,z)=0$.

Is there in $\mathbb{R}^2$ any example of that (We expect the parametrization to be continuously differentiable)?

In particular, I want to find a parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which image cannot be represented by an expression $f(x,y)=0$.

Comment: Please clarify what the 2D analogue of the 3D statement would mean exactly.

Comment: A curve $\gamma$ in $\mathbb R^2\subset \mathbb R^3$ is of course the intersection of $\mathbb R^2$ and $\gamma\times \mathbb R$ ...

Comment: If by *surface* yo mean a locally planar manifold, then any curve that crosses itself cannot lie on a surface. If you allow parametrized surfaces, than this is not a problem.

Comment: If the image of your parametrized curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is closed, then it can always be realized as the zero-set of a smooth function, even if it has self-intersections.   For *any* closed set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ (or, more generally, in any smooth manifold), we can find a smooth function $f$ such that $A= f^{-1}(0)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Theorem:*** For any closed set $C\in \mathbb{R^n}$ there exists a smooth function $f:\mathbb{R^n} \to \mathbb{R}$ s.t $f^{-1}(0)=C$.

so by using this theorem it is clear thatfor any closed parametrized curve that property which you are asking is true.

Otherwise in genral it is not true...for an instance consider $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R^2}$ $f(x)= (x,sin(1/x))$ is a perametrized curve but its image is not closed in $\mathbb{R^2}$...so it cannot be a zero set of a smooth function.